# How do I get info about an AppStore app in-app purchases in json form

Tags: ios, json, app-store, itunes

I know about http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=XXXXXXX but it doesn't provide any info about in-app purchases, google didn't help either, I wasn't able to find any question like this asked before. I'm new to programming so I can't think of another way to get this kind of info.